# C++ syntax for dereferencing class member variables

Tags: c++, class, pointers, syntax

This is more of a question of syntactic elegance, but I'm learning C++ and playing around with pointers. If I have a class, Car, I can create a pointer to a new instance of that class with

```
Car * Audi = new Car;
```

If that class has a member variable weight (an unsigned int, say), I can access it with either

```
(*Audi).weight
```

or

```
Audi->weight
```

If that class has a member variable age that is itself a pointer, I can access it with either

```
*((*Audi).age)
```

or

```
*(Audi->age)
```

Is there any other way than either of these two (admittedly not particularly complicated) ways of dereferencing the pointer? I wanted to think

```
Audi->*age
```

would work, but alas it does not.

(I appreciate that accessors are usually preferable, I'm just interested.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntactically, no, not unless you want to write a function or macro to do it. You could, but if you ask me, just use accessors. Also, you don't want to allocate most objects on the heap. Just declare them as `type foo;` or `type foo = type()` and let them be on the stack. You shouldn't put things on the heap with dynamic allocation unless you have a specific good reason to do so, as dynamic allocation has high overhead.

Answer (score 7):

```
*(Audi->age)
```

You don't need the parenthesis, because prefix operators have very low precedence:

```
*Audi->age
```

Answer (score 2):

No one has mentioned this way:

```
Audi->age[0]
```

Comment: Works, but is semantically iffy.  Looking at that, i now expect `age` to be pointing at an array, not just one thing.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way you would access the value pointed-to by `age` is the one you mention:

```
*(Audi->age)
```

There is a completely different meaning to `->*` that has to do with pointer-to-a-method.

In modern C++ you generally don't get into contact with pointers too much. Its all right to explore but, once you start to write real code, try to avoid pointers as much as possible. Stack is your friend :)

Comment: You don't need the parentheses, by the way.